# Laravel 5.4 Query DB with pivot table

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So, I have the following Tables named:

```
 ALBUMS(id, name, shared, group_id, user_id)
 GROUPS(id, name, user_id)
 GROUP_USER(group_id, user_id)
```

What I want to do is, using Laravel Eloquent to get the results of a query by checking if the AUTHENTICATED user is a member of the GROUP owned by the ALBUM.

Album Model:

```
public function groupSecurity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class, 'group_id');
}
```

Group Model:

```
    public function ownedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_user');
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You can use nested `wherehas` like : 

`$album = \App\Album::whereHas('groupSecurity.members', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    })->exists();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$album = Album::whereHas('groupSecurity', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('members', function($query2){
            $query2->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
        })->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    })->first();
```

So you search for one album that has a `groupSecurity` which has in his `members` the auth user and also it's `owned` by the auth user.
If a record match this conditions `$album` will have an instance of Album model, if not it will be null so you can do:

```
if($album){
    // AUTHENTICATED user is a member of the GROUP owned by the ALBUM
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It exactly what I need. Now what is left is to me to understant how it's working before tweaking it bit because of another condition. Thank you again =)